# macOS Monterey 12.4 Upgrade (from 12.1) failed despite sufficient disk space

Tags: macos, monterey

I understand that MacOS update usually means

1. Enough Disk space
2. Previous OS version isn't too old
3. At least x% charge

Despite all the above, my macOS Monterey upgrade to 12.4 failed. When I did `df -H` the below is shown

```
Filesystem       Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s5s1   251G    16G   119G    12%  577263 1166435320    0%   /
devfs            192k   192k     0B   100%     650          0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk1s4     251G   1.1G   119G     1%       2 1166435320    0%   /System/Volumes/VM
/dev/disk1s2     251G   503M   119G     1%    2551 1166435320    0%   /System/Volumes/Preboot
/dev/disk1s6     251G   113M   119G     1%     393 1166435320    0%   /System/Volumes/Update
/dev/disk1s1     251G   113G   119G    49%  888852 1166435320    0%   /System/Volumes/Data
map auto_home      0B     0B     0B   100%       0          0  100%   /System/Volumes/Data/home
/dev/disk1s5     251G    16G   119G    12%  577265 1166435320    0%   /System/Volumes/Update/mnt1
```

My installation is simply failing i.e. it downloads the OS files, and then installation fails after 1 hour. #

p.s. I am not using any fancy internet connection, it's plain wifi. no VPN/Tunelling, or nothing like that. I have never had any issue with MacOS update until this Monterey 12.4 came out. And the internet never drops

I mean, where is the issue here? I have more than sufficient resources, so is it my previous version (i.e. Monterey 12.1) or something else>

Regards,

Comment: Something else. 119GB free is ample. Do you have any error message when the install fails?  Alternatively find out how to download the full 12.4 macOS (about 12GB), create a bootable USB installer, boot it and install (without erasing).

Comment: it says "Please check your internet connection and try again" - nothing wrong with internet connection. How do I get detail log (e.g. event log) of what happened

Comment: I'm somewhat confused. The question seems to imply that the update fails because  there is not enough disk space, but your comment states something completely different: a problem with your Internet connection. Could you edit your answer and add a screenshot of the **actual** error message (or messages) you get when updating to 12.4? You write "nothing wrong with internet connection"... well, something seems to be wrong if the installer complains. Do you use VPN (like NordVPN) or firewall software (like Little Snitch)?

Comment: I have updated my question body to make it slightly clearer. Although, it's really not possible for me to know anything more than I already know. and that's how annoying this issue is right now